# Is there a way to pass a variable as parameter to int open() function in C?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I'm working on a project where I need to open a directory which is given as parameter and access every file in it, check some things on them and edit them and collect the results in a text file. However, when I try to access every single file through a while loop, the open() function doesn't work as expected. Here is the relative code:

```
    DIR *folder;
    struct dirent *entry;

    folder = opendir(argv[1]);
    if(folder == NULL){
        perror("Unable to read directory or directory doesn't exist");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if( (wfd=open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600)) == -1 ){
        perror("open");                                                 /*Creating the text file */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(wfd);
    
    while( (entry=readdir(folder)) ){
    
           fd=open(entry->d_name, O_RDONLY);

           if(fd == -1 ){
           perror("open1");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           } 
                                                  /*opening and reading the file*/
           bytes=read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));
           printf("%d bytes were read \n", bytes);
           close(fd);
           buf[bytes]='\0';
               .
               .    /*Rest of the code where I check edit and write the results in the outfile.txt*/
               .
    }
```

So as you can understand the

```
fd=open(entry->d_name, O_RDONLY);
```

part fails,following with the error message "open1: No such file or directory". I know the open() function needs a const* char,like, the exact name of the file name as "filename.txt" but how I'm supposed to do this when I hypothetically don't know the contents of the directory I'm working on? I tried to convert the entry->d_name variable to a char variable like this:

```
char entryName[255];
strncpy(entryName, entry->d_name, 254);
entryName[254]='\0';
```

and then

```
fd=open(entryName, O_RDONLY);
```

but I get the same error. Is there something I'm missing or it should be implemented in another way?

Comment: I think it fails because `entry->d_name` contains just the name of the file, not a _path_ to the file and since your current working directory is not `folder` you get "No such file or directory".

Comment: In general there is no problem with passing a variable to `open` or any other function that expects a string.  `const char *` just means that `open` promises not to modify the string that is passed to it.  It seems like you're thinking a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) is required, but that's not so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've `chdir()`ed into the target directory, you can't just do  `fd=open(entry->d_name, O_RDONLY);` expecting to open `entry->d_name` there. You'll probably want to use `fd = openat(dirfd(folder), entry->d_name, O_RDONLY)` instead.